# custom incorrect and correct alerts not displaying during javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am just about to submit my javascript project and i keep getting an error stating question within the incorrect and correct alert if statement is not defined. I have defined it earlier but i am now unsure how to target the quiz correctly to display incorrect and correct messages. Help very much appreciated for this javascript newbie.

```
// Splanets Quiz Questions, answers options, correct answer and image links 
let answer1 = document.getElementById("img1");
let answer2 = document.getElementById("img2");
let answer3 = document.getElementById("img3");
let answer4 = document.getElementById("img4");

let answerImages = [answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4];

let spQuiz = [
    {
        question: "What planet is closest to the Sun?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/venus.png",
            "assets/img/mercury.png",
            "assets/img/mars.png",
            "assets/img/earth.png"
        ],
            correctAnswer: '1'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet has the highest mountain in our solar system, a volcano named Olympus Mons?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/mars.png",
            "assets/img/jupiter.png",
            "assets/img/neptune.png",
            "assets/img/earth.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '0'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet has organic life?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/saturn.png",
            "assets/img/mars.png",
            "assets/img/earth.png",
            "assets/img/uranus.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '2'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet is the brightest in our solar system?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/mars.png",
            "assets/img/neptune.png",
            "assets/img/saturn.png",
            "assets/img/venus.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '3'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet is Nicknamed the Icy planet as it is the coldest one?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/neptune.png",
            "assets/img/saturn.png",
            "assets/img/uranus.png",
            "assets/img/mars.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '2'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet is 5th from the sun and the biggest in our solar system?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/saturn.png",
            "assets/img/mars.png",
            "assets/img/mercury.png",
            "assets/img/jupiter.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '3'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet is the smallest planet?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/mercury.png",
            "assets/img/earth.png",
            "assets/img/neptune.png",
            "assets/img/jupiter.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '0'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet has outer rings made of dust and ice chunks?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/venus.png",
            "assets/img/saturn.png",
            "assets/img/uranus.png",
            "assets/img/jupiter.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '1'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet is the hottest planet?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/mercury.png",
            "assets/img/mars.png",
            "assets/img/venus.png",
            "assets/img/jupiter.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '2'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet is furthest from the sun?",
        answers: [
            "assets/img/neptune.png",
            "assets/img/saturn.png",
            "assets/img/uranus.png",
            "assets/img/mercury.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '0'
    },
];

// Function to show Question and possible answers
let newQuestion = 0;
function displayQuestion () {
    let question = spQuiz[newQuestion];
    document.getElementById("question-text").innerHTML = question.question;
    let answers = question.answers;
    answer1.setAttribute("src", answers[0]);
    answer2.setAttribute("src", answers[1]);
    answer3.setAttribute("src", answers[2]);
    answer4.setAttribute("src", answers[3]);
    for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        let answer = answers[i];
    } 
}

//Event listener for answer, answer check & Score
let score = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < answerImages.length; i++) {
  answerImages[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (String(i) === spQuiz[newQuestion].correctAnswer) {
      score++;
    }
    newQuestion++;
    if (newQuestion < spQuiz.length) {
      displayQuestion();
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#score").innerHTML = "Your final score is " + score + " out of 10";
      if (score <= 9) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = "tryagain.html";
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = "rocketlaunch.html";
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  });
}

//correct & incorrect alert
let result = document.getElementById("result");

answerImages.forEach(function(answer, index) {
  answer.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (index == question.correctAnswer) {
      result.innerHTML = "Correct";
    } else {
      result.innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    }
  });
});
//Results Restart or Launch Rocket

//Call Quiz
displayQuestion();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SPLANETS</title>
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="assets/img/splanets.ico" rel="icon">
    <!-- Main Bootstrap Css-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Main CSS File -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Icons-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/128d236a07.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body id="bg-space">
    <!-- === Header === -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span ><i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/splanetslogo1.png" alt="Splanets Logo" class="img-fluid logo"></a>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Instructions</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="game.html">Restart Game</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- End of Header -->
    <!-- === Hero === -->
    <section id="quiz">
      <div id="quiz-question-card" class="container welcome-card shadow-lg text-dark mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div id="score" class="card-body">
          <h2 class="question-title">Question</h2>
          <p id="question-text"></p>
          <br>
          <p id="result"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div id="answer-btns" class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4">
          <img id="img1" src="" alt="">
          <img id="img2" src="" alt="">
          <img id="img3" src="" alt="">
          <img id="img4" src="" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="progress">

      </div>

    </section>


  <!-- End of Hero -->

<!-- === Footer === -->
<!-- End of Footer -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined "question" `let question = spQuiz[newQuestion];`, that variable is local to that function since it was defined there.

If you defined it outside the function then they should all be able to access it anywhere.

```
let question;
function displayQuestion () {
   question = spQuiz[newQuestion];
```

Comment: amazing thank you! all working now